# Dont understand the exception handeling in the case of changing interfaces as mentioned in Refactoring book by Fowler

Tags: java, refactoring

I'm reading the Fowler book on Refactoring. In chapter 2 in the changing interfaces section. I don't understand this passage:

> There is one particular area with problems in changing interfaces in
>   Java: adding an exception to the throws clause. This is not a change
>   in signature, so you cannot use delegation to cover it. The compiler
>   will not let it compile, however. It is tough to deal with this
>   problem. You can choose a new name for the method, let the old method
>   call it, and convert the checked into an unchecked exception. You can
>   also throw an unchecked exception, although then you lose the checking
>   ability. When you do this, you can alert your callers that the
>   exception will become a checked exception at a future date. They then
>   have some time to put the handlers into their code. For this reason I
>   prefer to define a superclass exception for a whole package (such as
>   SQLException for java.sql) and ensure that public methods only declare
>   this exception in their throws clause. That way I can define subclass
>   exceptions if I want to, but this won't affect a caller who knows only
>   about the general case.

Could someone explain with an example? Thanks a ton!

Comment: There's quite a lot *of* that passage - which part do you not understand?

Comment: I guess I dont understand how the expceptions are related to an interface.. For example this part: `There is one particular area with problems in changing interfaces in Java: adding an exception to the throws clause. This is not a change in signature, so you cannot use delegation to cover it. The compiler will not let it compile, however. It is tough to deal with this problem. You can choose a new name for the method, let the old method call it, and convert the checked into an unchecked exception.`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you currently have:

```
public interface Foo {
    void bar();
}
```

You cannot later evolve this to:

```
public interface Foo {
    void bar() throws SomeException;
}
```

(where `SomeException` is a checked exception) because code that previously called `bar()` won't be catching `SomeException`... it will fail to compile after the change. The suggested fix is to introduce a new method instead:

```
public interface Foo {
    void bar();
    var barWithException() throws SomeException;
}
```

... although then any *implementations* of `Foo` become invalid because they don't declare `barWithException()`.

The other alternative suggested is to make `SomeException` an unchecked exception, warning users that it might become checked later.

Comment: Whats up with the just `throws;` clause? could you explain that? thank you!

Comment: @TazMan: Sorry, that was just a typo. Fixed.